# Extract Chatter Post and Image

Tags: data-export, chatter-groups

Our company has a chatter group where we've captured all employees marriage and birth announcements. Our HR team would like to export all these post with images so they can make a book with them. Anyone know a way to export all content from a chatter group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SOQL statement will do the trick, you will just need to pull the group ID from the URL and use the Dataloader to export the data.

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Type, CreatedById, CreatedDate, IsDeleted, LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp, CommentCount, LikeCount, Title, Body, LinkUrl, RelatedRecordId, ContentData, ContentFileName, ContentDescription, ContentType, ContentSize, InsertedById FROM CollaborationGroupFeed WHERE ParentID = '<GroupID>'
```

In the URL `https://carbonite.my.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9E000000052ur` the **0F9E000000052ur** is the `<GroupID>`.